# Importing 3D model exported from Blender/maya in Threejs and rendering it using CanvasRenderer for iPad

Tags: three.js, blender

Am trying to create an app which will import the 3D model exported from Blender/Maya into ThreeJS. I have installed Blender and three js export option is also coming, however when am trying to load the exported JS (I tried renaming extension to json also) it is not working and showing blank screen. Can anyone help me with this by providing a sample code for this?
TIA.

Regards,

NileshW

Comment: Dave - I have deleted the post. Please reply to this post.

Comment: There are examples for every loader that comes with Three.js Just check them!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        var camera, scene, renderer;
        var geometry, material, mesh;

        var controls;

        init();
        animate();

        function init() {

            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 5, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000 );
            camera.position.set( 50, 50, 50 );

            controls = new THREE.TrackballControls( camera );

            controls.rotateSpeed = 1.0;
            controls.zoomSpeed = 1.2;
            controls.panSpeed = 0.8;

            controls.noZoom = false;
            controls.noPan = false;

            controls.staticMoving = false;
            controls.dynamicDampingFactor = 0.3;

            controls.keys = [ 65, 83, 68 ];

            scene = new THREE.Scene();
            var light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff);
            light.position.set(-100,200,100);
            scene.add(light);

              // Load in the mesh and add it to the scene.
            var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
            loader.load( "models/testnew.js", function(geometry){
            var material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial({color: 0x55B663});
                mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
                scene.add(mesh);
            });
            //
            renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
            renderer.setSize( 1000, 600);
            document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
        }

        function animate() {

            requestAnimationFrame( animate );

            controls.update();

            renderer.render( scene, camera );
            }
```

Comment: I tried above code and it works is iPad too(as I have used CanvasRenderer instead of WebGLRenderer which is not supported in iPad. I have one issue with this. When I try above code for below condition it doesnt work: 1. When I import a obj/3ds file in Blender and export for ThreeJS it doesnt show anything on screen. The above code only works for sample blender models not for any imported models. Any idea where I can get the other custom models working..

Comment: This section is for answers, not questions. You need to make a new post.

Answer (score 0):

add a div to the body

```
<div id="myScene"></div>
```

then..

```
<script>
// global 
            var scene, renderer, camera, cube, controls;

            init();
            animate();

            function init() {

                // scene box
                var myScene = document.getElementById("myScene");

                scene = new THREE.Scene();
                camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, .01, 10000);
                camera.position.z = 500;

                var light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff); // soft white light
                scene.add(light);



                var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
                directionalLight.position.set(1, 1, 1).normalize();
                scene.add(directionalLight);


                /*  ==== OPTIONAL SPOTLIGHT ==== 
                var spotLight = new THREE.SpotLight(0xffffff);
                spotLight.position.set(100, 1000, 2000);

                spotLight.castShadow = true;

                spotLight.shadowMapWidth = 1024;
                spotLight.shadowMapHeight = 1024;

                spotLight.shadowCameraNear = 500;
                spotLight.shadowCameraFar = 4000;
                spotLight.shadowCameraFov = 30;

                scene.add(spotLight);
                */

                renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
                renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
                myScene.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

                loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();

                loader.load("your_json_file.js", function (geometry, materials) {
                    mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial(materials));
                    scene.add(mesh);
                });

            }
            function animate() {
                requestAnimationFrame(animate);
                render();

            }
            function render() {

                renderer.render(scene, camera);
            }

</script>
```

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="js/three.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/loaders/JSONLoader.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/renderers/CanvasRenderer.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        var loader,mesh;
   var container, camera, scene, renderer;

Comment: function init() {
            container = document.createElement( 'div' );       document.body.appendChild( container );
            camera = new THREE.Camera( 70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000 );
            camera.position.y = 150;
            camera.position.z = 500;
camera.target.position.y = 150;
scene = new THREE.Scene();
loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();loader.load("test.js", function (geometry, materials) {
                    mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial(materials));
    scene.add(mesh);
     render1()
  });}

Comment: function render1()
  {
    renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
     container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
    renderer.render( scene, camera );  
  }
    </script>

Comment: Please let me know what am missing. Thanks!

Comment: i edited my example, if your .js file is in the root directory it should work.

Comment: I tried the code and its working with the model, now the issue is am not getting the model which I already have. I have 3DS exported obj file and am importing that in Blender and finally exporting for threejs am not sure but something is going wrong and am not getting any result when I try in my code with Canvas renderer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the code from chawk - just change to use your test.js (check folder path)

If the code in you function init() is complete then it looks like you've missed a couple of things

You have created a camera, created a scene, created a loader, loaded a file and added mesh to the scene

You need to add the camera to the scene
You also need to add some light(s) to your scene